# Resolve Promise when event fires without duplicating event listeners

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, promise, eventemitter

I am attempting to resolve a promise when an EventEmitter event is fired.

The containing function takes an argument and adds it to a stack. Items are then taken off the stack for arbitrary processing and either a `success` or `error` event is fired.

```
public async processData(payload: Payload) {
  // Push data onto a stack
  this._myStack.push(payload);

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    myEventEmitter.on('processSuccess', data => {
      resolve(data);
    });

    myEventEmitter.on('processError', error => {
      reject(error);
    });
  });
}
```

The issue is that a new listener is added every time an item is added to the stack. This means that when a `processSuccess` or `processError` event is emitted, the promise will return for every item on the stack.

Example: If there are 11 items on the stack and `processSuccess` is emitted, `data` will be returned 11 times.

Is there a way to resolve a promise when one of the events is emitted without returning for each item on the stack? That is to say, how can I accomplish this without creating a bunch of event listeners for each event?

Comment: what logic ensures that completion of processing stack items occurs in the order they were pushed on the stack?  That is, how do you know what payload an event is emitted for?

Comment: Data is taken from the top on the stack, processed, the completion event is emitted, and it is popped. `peek()` `process()` `emit()` `pop()`. There is identifying information in the returned payload itself. `myEventEmitter.emit('processSuccess', data);`

Comment: The code appears to wait for processing to succeed or fail after pushing a payload on the stack - how does more than one payload getting onto the stack at the same time ever happen or have I missed something?

Comment: If I call this method 5 times with 5 different arguments then it will add all 5 to the stack. The actual processing of an item on the stack occurs when a user chooses to process it (removed from example for simplicity). At which time, either `processSuccess` or `processError` is emitted and the processed item (the one the user chose to take action on) is removed and the user has the option to act on the next item on the stack.

Comment: Got it. The `return await new Promise(async ....)` was confusing me - it doesn't need the `await` operator or `async` declaration in the executor.

Comment: Whoops, totally missed that. I’ll edit and remove

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you can use the payload identifying information from the `data` itself that is sent with the event (for both success and error), then you can do it like this:

```
public processData(payload: Payload) {
    // Push data onto a stack
    this._myStack.push(payload);

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

      function resolver(data) {
        // if this event belongs to this payload
        if (data.payload === payload) {
          resolve(data);
          clearHandlers();
        }
      }

      function rejecter(error) {
        // if this event belongs to this payload
        if (error.payload === payload) {
          reject(error);
          clearHandlers();
        }
      }

      // clear event handlers
      function clearHandlers() {
        myEventEmitter.removeListener('processSuccess', resolver);
        myEventEmitter.removeListener('processError', rejecter);
      }

      myEventEmitter.on('processSuccess', resolver);  
      myEventEmitter.on('processError', rejecter);
    });
}
```

If you can't identify which payload corresponds with which event, then the only way to use this general structure is to never have the same `myEventEmitter` being used for more than one `processData()` operation at a time.  That's because you need to make sure that when a `processSuccess` or `processError` event occurs, you know exactly which payload it belongs to.  You have to know that to avoid cross coupling between separate async operations in flight at the same time.  That can be accomlished in four ways:

1. The payload is part of every event so you can compare to see if it's the right payload (like in my first code example).
2. A `myEventEmitter` object is never shared between operations that are in flight at the same time.
3. No two async operations that are using a shared `myEventEmitter` are ever in flight at the same time.
4. You somehow conjure up unique message names to both listen to and trigger for each separate payload that is running.  This would require cooperation with the event triggering side of things too.

For options #2 or #3 above, you could use this code:

```
public processData(payload: Payload) {
    // Push data onto a stack
    this._myStack.push(payload);

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      function resolver(data) {
        resolve(data);
        clearHandlers();
      }
      function rejecter(err) {
        reject(error);
        clearHandlers();
      }
      // clear event handlers
      function clearHandlers() {
        myEventEmitter.removeListener('processSuccess', resolver);
        myEventEmitter.removeListener('processError', rejecter);
      }

      myEventEmitter.on('processSuccess', resolver);  
      myEventEmitter.on('processError', rejecter);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use event Namespacing. refer https://css-tricks.com/namespaced-events-jquery/

Make some sort of dynamic namespace for events, and run a check for that namespace to match in a common event listener. Resolve promise when any of the namespace matches.

Comment: I don't believe namespacing is supported in the node EventEmitter.

Answer (score 0):

so basically for an good answer I'd require a little more information, but overall it you are able to do the following:

- Payload should have an unique id
- Data response should contain the same id
- Error response should contain the same id

So based on that your payload object should something like this:

```
{"id": ..., ....}
```

Response data object

```
{"id": ..., ....}
```

Error data object

```
{"id": ..., ....}
```

You could easily do something like this:

```js
class MyClass {
    private _myStack: Array<Payload>;
    private _promisesFunctions: Array<any>;

    constructor() {
        myEventEmitter.on('processSuccess', data => {
            this._promisesFunctions[data.id].resolve(data);
        });

        myEventEmitter.on('processError', error => {
            this._promisesFunctions[error.id].reject(error);
        });
    }

    public async processData(payload: Payload) {
        // Push data onto a stack
        this._myStack.push(payload);

        return await new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
            this._promisesFunctions[payload.id] = { resolve, reject };
        });
    }
 }
```

If you don't have this possibility or you can't control those 3 objects, please provide examples of all this 3 object or at least more information about this issue and I'll update my response

Comment: Sorry for the limited info. Trying to simplify as much as possible. I do control all three objects so this looks like a great solution. I'll test it out as soon as I have a minute